# Log file not populated with log info

Tags: java, log4j

I have below log4j.properties and the specified log file is not created. I am using log4j-1.2.13 version.
    could please help me out.

```
**log4j.properties:**

log4j.logger.kmc.debug=INFO,console,file

log4j.appender.AuditFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.AuditFile.File=${log.dir}/rkm_java_client_audit.log
log4j.appender.AuditFile.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.AuditFile.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.AuditFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AuditFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ}


# Audit logs to EventLog on a Windows system.
log4j.appender.AuditEventlog=org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender
log4j.appender.AuditEventlog.Source=RKMJavaClient_2_1
#log4j.appender.AuditEventlog.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.AuditEventlog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AuditEventlog.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
```

Comment: First check whether the log file is generated at default place or not. To do so, specify log file name directly, like, `log4j.appender.AuditFile.File=rkm_java_client_audit.log`. This should create a log file directly in WAR folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the file appender in your log4j.properties. Here is how you can do it:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\loging.log 
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1 
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n**
```

Follow this link to learn more: http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/

Comment: yes I too have that already in my log4j.properties.

# sysout is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${log.dir}/rkm_java_client_status.log
log4j.appender.file.Append=true

# sysout uses PatternLayout to print the message.
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ} %5p [%t] %m%n

Comment: Still I am not getting the "km_java_client_status.log" / "rkm_java_client_audit.log" file in log location.
could you please suggest.

Comment: below log4j prop

# The directory to output file logs to
log.dir=logs

log4j.logger.kmc.debug=INFO,console,file
#log4j.logger.kmc.debug=INFO,console,file

# Audit logs to file for test purposes.
log4j.appender.AuditFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.AuditFile.File=${log.dir}/rkm_java_client_audit.log
log4j.appender.AuditFile.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.AuditFile.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.AuditFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AuditFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ} %X{hostname} %5p [RKMJavaClient_${kmjc.version}] %m%n

Comment: # Audit logs to syslog on a Linux/Unix system.
log4j.appender.AuditSyslog=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.AuditSyslog.Name=syslog
log4j.appender.AuditSyslog.SyslogHost=127.0.0.1
log4j.appender.AuditSyslog.Facility=RKMJavaClient_2_1
log4j.appender.AuditSyslog.FacilityPrinting=true
log4j.appender.AuditSyslog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AuditSyslog.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

Comment: # Audit logs to EventLog on a Windows system.
log4j.appender.AuditEventlog=org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender
log4j.appender.AuditEventlog.Source=RKMJavaClient_2_1
#log4j.appender.AuditEventlog.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.AuditEventlog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AuditEventlog.layout.ConversionPattern=

Comment: # sysout is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.console.Threshold=ERROR

# sysout uses PatternLayout to print the message.
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

# sysout is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${log.dir}/rkm_java_client_status.log
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
# sysout uses PatternLayout to print the message.
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

Comment: log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ} %5p [%t] %m%n

# sysout is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.detail.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# sysout uses PatternLayout to print the message.
log4j.appender.detail.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.detail.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ}] %-5p %c#%C#%M - %m%n

log4j.logger.kmc.audit=ALL, AuditFile
#log4j.logger.kmc.audit=INFO, AuditSyslog
#log4j.logger.kmc.audit=INFO, AuditEventlog

Comment: #-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------#
# STDOUT is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# STDOUT uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p (%c.java:%L).%M - %m%n

#------------------------------------ROLL------------------------------------#
# ROLL is set to be a RollingFileAppender.
log4j.appender.ROLL=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

Comment: #log4j.appender.ROLL.File=/logs/myFile.log
log4j.appender.ROLL.File=${log.dir}/rkm_java_client_status.log
log4j.appender.ROLL.MaxFileSize=1MB
# Keep five backup files
log4j.appender.ROLL.MaxBackupIndex=5

log4j.appender.ROLL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ROLL.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c.%M:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.ROLL.Encoding=UTF-8

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#


log4j.logger.org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.ibm._jsp=DEBUG

Comment: Could you please help me out.
Note: logs are not getting which is there in the liberaries.

Comment: @user1280096 What is the challenge right now? I see too many comments.

Answer (score 0):

May you need to add the following line (usually at the beginning):

```
# Set root logger level to INFO and its appenders to console, file.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console, file
```

See the next example:

```
# Set root logger level to INFO and appender to ROLL.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, ROLL

#-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------#
# STDOUT is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# STDOUT uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p (%c.java:%L).%M - %m%n

#------------------------------------ROLL------------------------------------#
# ROLL is set to be a RollingFileAppender.
log4j.appender.ROLL=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.ROLL.File=/logs/myFile.log
log4j.appender.ROLL.MaxFileSize=1MB
# Keep five backup files
log4j.appender.ROLL.MaxBackupIndex=5

log4j.appender.ROLL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ROLL.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c.%M:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.ROLL.Encoding=UTF-8

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Specify the logging level for loggers from other libraries

log4j.logger.org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.ibm._jsp=DEBUG

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html
```

Comment: Could you please see my above comments in the first answer part.